# How to prove the result of an integral of partial derivatives

Tags: integration, partial-derivative

[image]

I have proof for question a but I cannot proof question b. How should I prove question b?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Using your answer in (a), you can develop a (very simple) lower bound for $|v(t)|$, from which your inequality will follow. You can think of $T$ as $\int_0^T dt$ if you like...